# Origem da expressão "de ponta-cabeça"

Tags: etimologia, português-brasileiro, expressões-idiomáticas

No Brasil (ao menos no Estado de São Paulo) é muito comum o uso da expressão "de ponta cabeça" com o sentido de "de cabeça para baixo", ou "de pés para o ar" — equivalente ao "upside down" do inglês.

Encontrei no [Dicio.com](http://www.dicio.com.br/ponta-cabeca/) uma definição com hífen:

> de ponta-cabeça, que significa "de cabeça para baixo".

Encontramos a mesma definição no [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/ponta-cabe%C3%A7a), conforme mencionado pelo @JorgeB.

O [VOLP](http://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/busca-no-vocabulario) reconhece a expressão, e ainda no plural:

> ponta-cabeça s.f.; pl. pontas-cabeça e pontas-cabeças

Me parece que a expressão só é entendida por quem já a conhece, pois carece de sentido óbvio.

Qual é sua origem? Há alguma razão lógica que justifique tal construção?

Comment: No Rio de Janeiro eu nunca ouvi a expressão.

Comment: Também vem no [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/ponta-cabe%C3%A7a) e no Houaiss. Aqui em Portugal nunca ouvi.

Comment: Acho ótimo “de ponta cabeça” em lugar de “de cabeça para baixio” em todos os possíveis usos: é uma expressão mais concisa, mais sonora, mais expressiva e até mais poética. Não foi por acaso que Monteiro Lobato a usou no caso da Alice

Comment: Considerando brincadeiras de criança antes da era da informática, as crianças brincavam muito com um brinquedo de girar chamado peão, que ao ficar invertido, ficava com a ponta (que deveria ficar para baixo) para cima no lugar da cabeça (parte maior do peão). É apenas minha opinião.

Comment: Sempre escutei esta expressão quando criança é minha vó sempre dizia "Não fica de ponta cabeça " quando brincávamos de plantar bananeira, não sei a origem mas minha avó era nordestina não sei se tem alguma origem de lá, só me dei conta disso agora depois de muito tempo e me perguntei, porque "de ponta cabeça" mesmo assim eu entendo a expressão que sempre ouvi em São Paulo

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Originalmente a expressão usava-se apenas a propósito de quedas ou mergulhos: ***cair de ponta-cabeça*** ou ***precipitar-se de ponta-cabeça***. Isto parece ser uma variante de ***cair de ponta e cabeça***, que também se usa no Brasil, o que por sua vez é um reforço de ***cair de cabeça***, que se usa em todo lado.

Atualmente *de ponta-cabeça* significa geralmente ‘de pernas para o ar, de cabeça para baixo’. Mas o uso da expressão fora do contexto de quedas é recente: no Google Books aparece apenas a partir de 1979. E dois dicionários dos anos setenta restringem o uso da expressão a quedas:

> **De ponta-cabeça**, head first. [literalmente, ‘cabeça primeiro’; [Oswaldo Serpa, *Dicionário de Expressões Idiomáticas Português-Inglês, Inglês-Português*, 1972.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=YqwUAQAAIAAJ&q=%22de%20ponta%20cabe%C3%A7a%22&dq=%22de%20ponta%20cabe%C3%A7a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_x9Cs-8_OAhVLaxQKHfx_CpU4ZBDoAQi4ATAX)]
>
> *de ponta-cabeça* que significa “de cabeça para baixo” (falando de queda). [[Pequeno dicionário enciclopédico Koogan Larousse*, 1979.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=2t8uAAAAYAAJ&q=%22de%20ponta%20cabe%C3%A7a%22&dq=%22de%20ponta%20cabe%C3%A7a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_x9Cs-8_OAhVLaxQKHfx_CpU4ZBDoAQilATAU)

Nos exemplos mais antigos que encontrei o contexto é sempre queda. O primeiro é de 1923 em Monteiro Lobato (1892-1948), “Era no Paraíso…” em *O Macaco que se fez homem* ([conto completo na Folha de São Paulo, 2008](http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/ilustrada/2008/04/395351-confira-trecho-de-o-macaco-que-se-fez-homem.shtml?mobile); negrito meu em todas as citações):

> Mas Eolo suspirou no seu antro e um forte pé-de-vento deu, que vascolejou com frenesi a árvore e fez o chimpanzé macho, perdido o equilíbrio, **precipitar-se de ponta-cabeça ao chão**.

Monteiro Lobato emprega ainda a expressão, sempre com o verbo cair — «caíam de ponta cabeça», «caiu duma vez ao chão de ponta cabeça» e «caiu de novo de ponta cabeça» — na sua [tradução de *Alice no País do Espelho*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=SzruAAAAMAAJ&q=%22ponta%20cabe%C3%A7a%22&dq=%22ponta%20cabe%C3%A7a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixloaU5s_OAhXG7BQKHYDTDJo4-gEQ6AEIxgEwHA). Não descobri a data, mas o senhor morreu em 1948. E o [*Boletim Trimestral da Comissão Catarinense de Folclore* de 1950](https://books.google.pt/books?id=qrcMAAAAYAAJ&q=%22ponta%20cabe%C3%A7a%22&dq=%22ponta%20cabe%C3%A7a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVlISl6M_OAhVBuhQKHfHoBn44yAEQ6AEIkQEwEg) também documenta a expressão e dá como exemplo «ele caiu de ponta-cabeça».

*De ponta **e** cabeça* aparece no Google Books com menos frequência, mas usada exatamente do mesmo modo. Os exemplos mais antigos que encontrei foram na obra do escritor brasileiro Paulo Dantas (1922-2007):

> Não é aquêle entrar louco, **de ponta e cabeça**, nos abismos gostosos. [[Paulo Dantas, *Viadutos*, 1968.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=PDFTAAAAMAAJ&q=%22de%20ponta%20e%20cabe%C3%A7a%22&dq=%22de%20ponta%20e%20cabe%C3%A7a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwvqHv78_OAhVCVBQKHSSMClQQ6AEIPTAF)
>
> Mergulho **de ponta e cabeça** nessas favelas [[Paulo Dantas, *O Lobo do Planalto*, 1970.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=kHgtAAAAYAAJ&q=%22de%20ponta%20e%20cabe%C3%A7a%22&dq=%22de%20ponta%20e%20cabe%C3%A7a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwvqHv78_OAhVCVBQKHSSMClQQ6AEINzAE)

Estas expressões aparecem na linguagem oral, e só muito mais tarde aparecem na escrita. Por isso não dou grande relevância a *de ponta e cabeça* surgir no Google Books só depois de *de ponta-cabeça*. Portanto vemos que quer *de ponta-cabeça* quer *de ponta e cabeça* aparecem primeiro usados simplesmente no sentido de *de cabeça*. Esta última vem já documentada no Dicionário de Moraes da Silva de 1789 (verbete *cabeça*; grafia original):

> § *De cabeça*; i. é, com a cabeça para baixo: *v. g.* “lançar alguem no rio *de cabeça.*”

Investiguei uma outra hipótese, mas tive de a abandonar por falta completa de indícios. Os primeiros registos da *ponta-cabeça* no Google Books ocorrem em zona de imigração italiana: Monteiro Lobato cresceu em Taubaté, São Paulo; e Santa Catarina também recebeu italianos. Como a expressão é desconhecida em Portugal, haveria a possibilidade de ter vindo de Itália. Procurei *punta capo* no Google, mas não encontrei nada de relevante. Vi em [*capo* neste dicionário muito completo](http://www.dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?parola=capo) e também em [*punta*](http://www.dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?parola=punta), e mais uma vez não encontrei nada. Parece-me portanto que nos resta a hipótese plausível da evolução a partir de *(cair, atirar-se) de cabeça*.

Comment: +1 Muito bem elaborada. Só não dei o accept de imediato para não inibir novas postagens.

Comment: @Bacco Não tens de dar explicações. Eu também espero sempre uns dias antes de aceitar. Correu bem, esta pergunta: encontrei material em que apoiar a resposta. Nalgumas questões de etimologia quase não se encontra nada.